# Bad ping times on OpenVPN for Android on Chromebook

Tags: android, openvpn, chromebook

I'm connecting my Asus C101 Chromebook to an OpenVPN server using the "OpenVPN for Android" app. The ping times are horrendous: ranging from 200ms to over a second.

If I use the same app, connecting to the same server, on the same Wifi, but on my Samsung tablet, the ping times are a much more consistent 160ms or so.

Is there something wrong with my Chromebook?

Comment: Are you really using the Android App "OpenVPN for Android" or the built-in openvpn (Network / VPN )?

Comment: I'm using the Android app on both. I'm testing the ping times with termux.

Comment: I *think* the ping times might be worse due to the fact that ChromeOS is emulating Android; so maybe that's why.